# Why java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: is thrown when try to print the piece of code "stream3.collect(Collectors.toList());"?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java heap space` error is thrown when executing below code.

```
Stream<String> stream3 = Stream.generate(() -> {return "afdajfkljflks";});

System.out.println(stream3.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Why specifically **java heap space** error and what scene behind of this piece of code `System.out.println(stream3.collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Answer (score 10):

[`Stream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-):

> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided Supplier.

`Collectors.toList` will try to create a list large enough to take all of the elements in the stream. There are infinity of those, and the JVM can't allocate a list with that many elements.

Comment: "There are infinity of those, JVM can't allocate a list with that many elements" ergh java is so trash why does anyone still use it

Comment: @Michael what languages do you know that can allocate infinitely-large lists? (And I'm not meaning languages that can handle infinitely-large streams, because Java can too).

Comment: I was kidding, I just liked your phrasing!

Comment: @Michael actually, it’s not a problem of the JVM but the OP’s machine which doesn’t have enough RAM for the infinite list.

Comment: @Holger We didn't say it was a problem with the JVM. Andy said the JVM *can't*. He didn't say why it can't.

Comment: @Michael I didn’t want to imply that you said that, I just addressed the comment to you both. Actually, you may consider the current JVMs/JREs insufficient, as even with infinite RAM, they weren’t capable of creating such a list, but due to the absence of infinite RAM we’ll never hit this limitation. We could emulate the right behavior by simply never returning from `collect`, but whether this is an improvement, is debatable.

Answer (score 4):

`Stream.generate` creates an infinite stream. You are trying to put infinite items into a list.

Does your JVM have infinite heap space? No.

If you want a stream with a single element, use

```
Stream.of("afdajfkljflks")
```